# ASP.Net Web API Repository Update Error 500

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

My Web Api Controller has an `UpdateArea` method which is passed an `id` and the updated values in the body. It is written as follows:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateArea(Guid id, [FromBody] AreaForUpdateDto areaForUpdateDto)
{
    // Check that the 'area' object parameter can be de-serialised to a AreaForUpdateDto.
    if (areaForUpdateDto == null)
    {
        _logger.LogError("AreasController.UpdateArea failed: Could not map area object parameter to a AreaForUpdateDto");

        // Return an error 400.
        return BadRequest();
    }

    // Ensure that the Area exists.
    var areaEntityFromRepo = _areaRepository.GetArea(id);

    // Map(source object (Dto), destination object (Entity))
    Mapper.Map(areaForUpdateDto, areaEntityFromRepo);
    _areaRepository.UpdateArea(areaEntityFromRepo);

    // Save the updated Area entity, added to the DbContext, to the SQL database.
    if (await _areaRepository.SaveChangesAsync())
    {
        var areaFromRepo = _areaRepository.GetArea(id);
        if (areaFromRepo == null)
            return NotFound();

        var area = Mapper.Map<AreaDto>(areaFromRepo);
        return Ok(area);
    }

    // The save has failed.
    _logger.LogWarning($"Updating Area {id} failed on save.");
    throw new Exception($"Updating Area {id} failed on save.");
}
```

This works fine until my application calls for an update, but the body of the request is identical to the existing data in the database. When this happens the `_areaRepository.SaveChangesAsync()` fails returning an `error 500`.

This happens if the user opens an Edit Details dialog, does not change anything and then clicks the Edit button sending the request.

I could validate on the client, which is fine, but I was surprised that this caused an error.

Can anybody please explain why this is failing and where I should correct this?

Comment: HTTP 500 means a server-side exception. What is the exception?

Comment: Does `SaveChangesAsync` return a `bool` or an `int`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the logic explained by you

> This happens if the user opens an Edit Details dialog, does not change anything and then clicks the Edit button sending the request.

and this snippet of code

```
//...code removed for brevity

// Save the updated Area entity, added to the DbContext, to the SQL database.
if (await _areaRepository.SaveChangesAsync())
{
    var areaFromRepo = _areaRepository.GetArea(id);
    if (areaFromRepo == null)
        return NotFound();

    var area = Mapper.Map<AreaDto>(areaFromRepo);
    return Ok(area);
}

// The save has failed.
_logger.LogWarning($"Updating Area {id} failed on save.");
throw new Exception($"Updating Area {id} failed on save.");
```

if no changes were made to the file and an update was attempted then no changes would be made to the `DbContext` which means that `_areaRepository.SaveChangesAsync()` would be `false` and thus continue on to

```
// The save has failed.
_logger.LogWarning($"Updating Area {id} failed on save.");
throw new Exception($"Updating Area {id} failed on save.");
```

and **BAM** 500 error on the server.

I recommend debugging/stepping through the suspect code to confirm its behavior is as explained above and then rethink and refactor the update logic.

Comment: Yes, of course. So in this situation should I somehow handle this more gracefully in my controller or should I prevent the request ever being made?

Comment: @TDC that is totally up to you. if there are no changes to send to the server then save the trip. You could also not throw an exception and provided a model state message back to the client.

Comment: I think I will evaluate the object before sending the request for equality. Thanks for the prompt and concise answer.